# Titel of titledborder needs to be clickable

Tags: java, jpanel, mouseevent, border, titled-border

I want to create a panel with a titledborder. And the title needs to be clickable. Is there a way to do this? Because when I place a mouslistener on the panel you can click everywhere on the panel the event happens. And it must be triggered only when I click on the title of the titledborder

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs it, here is a working example as per camickr's suggestion.

```
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
            final Border border = panel.getBorder();
            if (border instanceof TitledBorder) {
                final TitledBorder tb = (TitledBorder) border;
                final FontMetrics fm = panel.getFontMetrics(panel.getFont());
                final int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(tb.getTitle()) + 20;
                final Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, titleWidth, fm.getHeight());
                if (bounds.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                   // YOUR BUSINESS LOGIC
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that displays a tooltip when you hover over the title of the TitledBorder:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TitledBorderTest
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
        Border lowerEtched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
        String titleText = "Long title that will be truncated in the panel";
        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lowerEtched, titleText);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Border border = getBorder();

                if (border instanceof TitledBorder)
                {
                    TitledBorder tb = (TitledBorder)border;
                    FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics( getFont() );
                    int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(tb.getTitle()) + 20;
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, titleWidth, fm.getHeight());
                    return bounds.contains(e.getPoint()) ? super.getToolTipText() : null;
                }

                return super.getToolTipText(e);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder( title );
        panel.setToolTipText(title.getTitle());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The concept should be similar when using a MouseListener on the panel.

Comment: No, I don't know how to create my situation, because I can't place  a mouseaddapter on a border

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren - I didn't suggest to add the MouseAdapter to the Border. Read my last comment. The getToolTipText() method has the MouseEvent as a parameter. So your MouseLIstener will also have the MouseEvent as a parameter. Instead of "returning the tool tip text" your code would invoke your mouseClick() logic.